# Scala Parser Combinators issue with whitespaces

Tags: scala, parsing, first-order-logic

I am writing the parser for first-order conditions. I am using Scala and the scala-parser-combinators library. It works well, but I discovered this issue.

Here, I report the clause for negation (example: not predicate(p1)). It uses recursion, calling fol_condition, i.e. the root level rule for fol conditions:

```
def fol_negation : Parser[Negation] = "not"~fol_condition ^^ {case _~sub => Negation(sub)}
```

So, a string like "not predicate(p1)" produces the correct result Negation(Predicate("predicate",...))
However, when I parse a string like "note(p2)", it should produce a Predicate("note",...); instead, it returns Negation(Predicate(a,...)). In other words, the parser ignores whether there is a space between "not" and the following fol_condition.

This is not the desired behaviour. I would inform the parser that "not a" is different from "nota" because there is a space in between.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

It's not about whitespaces. It's about the precedence between reserved keywords and identifiers.

Neither in `not(P(x))` nor in `note(y)` are there any whitespaces, yet the problem is the same.

You don't want to force the user to type a whitespace after every `not`, because `not (P(x) and Q(y))` would be awkward.

What you might try to do instead:

**A.** Reorder your grammar such that all rules that start with an identifier come first; Then the branch in which `note(y)` is parsed as `note`-identifier will be taken first, and the problem disappears; For this to work, you obviously would have to exclude all the reserved keywords from the set of valid identifiers.

**B.** If you just want a quick fix, use a lookahead regex like `"not(?=\W)".r` instead of the fixed character sequence `"not"`, and make the `not`-rule (and all the other keyword-related rules) come before the `identifier`-rules.